# I have to pass a name from an input form in my ejs file and handle it in my post request

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have an ejs file where i want the user to enter into the form an username which i will then use in my .get request to do some logic, but my usename isnt correctly being got its showing as undefined.

index.ejs:

```html
<form action="/entry" method="GET">
  <label>Enter Name <input  type="text" name="name"></label>
  <input class="submitbtn" type="submit" value="index" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">
</form>
```

enrty.js where i have my get request:

```js
router.get("/entry" , async(req, res) => {
  const allEntries = await  dailyUsage.find();

  const {name} = req.body;
  console.log(name);

  // ...
}
```

I want ̀name` to contain the username entered from the form, but without using bodyparser or middleware. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your form is using `GET` method, you won't find `name` in `req.body`, but in `req.query`:

```
const {name} = req.query;
```